# Trying to make an INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sql

```
step2 = "INSERT INTO Products" & _
            "(ProductID, ProductName,UnitPrice)'"
step2 = AddValue(step2, Text7) & "', '"
step2 = AddValue(step2, Text15) & "', '"
step2 = AddValue(step2, Text9) & "' FROM Products"

Private Function AddValue(qry As String, txtbox As TextBox) As String

txtbox.SetFocus
AddValue = qry & txtbox.Text
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)